# TracAccountManager in global plugins [inherit] with acct_mgr.admin.accountmanageradminpanel doesn't show admin panel

Tags: trac

I have the following set in trac.ini:

```
[components]
acct_mgr.admin.accountmanageradminpanel = enabled

[inherit]
plugins_dir = ../../plugins
```

and in a global plugins folder I have TracAccountManager-0.5.dev0-py2.7.egg.

However, I don't see the account manager admin panel still. Putting it in the project specific plugins folder seems to resolve the issue. I'd rather have it be globally inherited. Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

Forgot to add the following details:

This is on Windows 7, and trac version is 1.2.2.

Let me know if any other details are needed.

**EDIT**:

It seems to be picking up the plugin b.c. if I go to the admin tab and then manage plugins, the plugin shows up as tracaccountmanager 0.5.dev0. After seeing this, I've confirmed that I do *not* have a copy of it in the project specific plugins folder.

I've also characterized the inherited plugins dir to be relative to the project env specific plugins dir.

Comment: Which Trac version? Are you running on Linux? I wonder if relative paths aren't handled correctly. I will test, but you might want to try using an absolute path.

Comment: @RjOllos see edits

Comment: Try: `acct_mgr.* = enabled`.

Comment: `acct_mgr.admin.accountmanageradminpanel` probably has a dependency on another component. You'll probably find loading of the component is skipped if you enable [Logging](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTroubleshooting#ChecktheLogs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the `[components]` configuration it seems that the documentation for https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin/Modules#AccountManagerAdminPanel is not working for me. Instead of using

```
[components]
acct_mgr.admin.AccountManagerAdminPanel = enabled
```

as the documentation suggests, I'm finding better success using

```
[components]
acct_mgr.admin.configurationadminpanel = enabled
acct_mgr.admin.useradminpanel = enabled
acct_mgr.api.accountmanager = enabled
acct_mgr.notification.accountchangenotificationadminpanel = enabled
```

I concluded this from going to the admin plugins section and expanding the `tracaccountmanager 0.5.dev0` section, clicking enable all, then started disabling components in batches or individually. In fact, I don't think `acct_mgr.admin.AccountManagerAdminPanel` does anything from what I've observed.

Answer (score 0):

Non-absolute paths are relative to the Environment `conf` directory. You probably need to modify your relative path. I will update the Trac documentation to specify this detail.